# Xcode - Localized images not working on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization, ios6

I'm testing a app on my iPhone. The localized images works fine in simulator, but not works on device! Everything seems correct in Xcode and with the folders structure of my bundle.

I've uninstalled the app from iPhone and rebuild it, cleaned, but don't work!

The default app language is english, alternative is portuguese. The strings appears in english, but the images always in portuguese.

(Temporarily my iPhone is in English, for testing.)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an example a while ago that demonstrates using different images for different locales, as well as in easy way to test them:

https://github.com/Abizern/SimpleLocalisationTesting

See if you are doing similar to load / display localised images. In this example I load the image using a localised name, so that different locales can use specific images.

Comment: Thanks! I knew this technique, just wanted to avoid it, since it's a lot of pictures. But that's what I ended up doing, I can't figure out how to do localized images (without using Localizable.strings) work properly! :/

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are seeing different behaviour in iOS simulator could have something to do with XCode not removing old files when deploying to the simulator. Try deleting your app in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[SDKVersion]/Applications. I think this should solve the discrepancy between iOS Simulator and an actual iPhone.

After this iOS Simulator issue is solved, you'll probably realize the your localized images don't get deployed to the xx.lproj folder.

Comment: Doesn't work ... = / Images still working properly located in the simulator, but the images appear only in Portuguese on the iPhone.